# WebGL. Объединение двух объектов

Tags: javascript, webgl

У меня на сцене есть два объекта разных цветов и мне нужно их объединить в один, если они друг на друга накладываются.
В 3d моделирование есть булевы операции.

- Объединение (соединение объектов в один).
- Пересечение (в булевый
  объект входят только общие части исходных объектов).
- Исключение
  (вырезание).
  И мне нужно написать такую вот штуку.

```
+-------+            +-------+
|       |            |       |
|   A   |            |       |            
|    +--+----+   =   |       +----+
+----+..+....|       +----+       |
     |...B...|            |       |
     |.......|            |       |
     +-------+            +-------+
```

Хотя сегодня утром проснулся и подумал, что наверняка есть библиотека, которая может помочь реализовать такой функционал. Наткнулся на csg.js.

Изучаю WebGL и не знаю как реализовать такой функционал. Не могу найти ни какой инфы по этой теме.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: собственно вы уже нашли подходящую библиотеку которая помогла бы вам (csg.js). Попробуйте воспользоваться ею почитав документацию и разобравшись в ней - голый webGL API вам мало поможет.